# Angular 6 on Subpath with HashRouter fails to load image assets

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

I need to deploy an existing angular 6 app on different environments with each different subpaths.

for Example: root.com/appRoot1

My assets don't load correctly because it's hosted on a subpath so I googled and **found the baseHref** and how to set it dynamically but it didn't work because I'm using HashRouter.

So I googled more and **found deployUrl** which changed the link to scripts and stylesheets to /appRoot1/stylesheet.css which is great.

But other assets like images **still won't load correctly**. The browser tries to request

```
/images/image.svg
```

instead of

```
/appRoot1/images/image.svg
```

In the code images are referenced like this:

```
<img src="../../../../../assets/images/image.svg" />
```

Additionally it would be great if I could set this dynamically since I need to deploy to different urls with different subpaths.

I'm a react user and I didn't write the code for this project so it is really hard for me to debug.